# How to catch a SMS from Twilio with Cypress IO?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, twilio, cypress

I have found this code on one of the tutorials to catch SMS from Twilio and pass it to ur webdriver test. I need help to catch the sms using Cypress. I need help using **async-await** instead of **browser.call** with Cypress.

```
const accountSid = 'YOUR_SID';
const authToken = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

describe('OTP', () => {
  it('Login with OTP', () => {
    const username = $('#login_field');
    const pass = $('#password');
    const signInBtn = $('input[type="submit"]');
    const otpField = $('#otp');
    const verifyBtn = $(
      'form[action="/sessions/two-factor"] button[type="submit"]'
    );

    browser.url('https://github.com/login');
    username.setValue('your_email@mail.com');
    pass.setValue('your_pass123');
    signInBtn.click();

    // Get OTP ...
    const otp = browser.call(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          client.messages.list({ limit: 1 }).then((messages) =>
            messages.forEach((m) => {
              // console.log(m.body.match(/\d+/)[0]);
              resolve(m.body.match(/\d+/)[0]);
            })
          );
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });

    otpField.setValue(otp);
    verifyBtn.click();
    expect(browser).toHaveUrl('https://github.com/');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Manzeel Uprety you can try my solution:

```
const accountSid = 'AC793683c4982a14f01714321bd3f90ca7';
const authToken = '819068e54369ac58bb8aad976fa517bc';
const githubEmail = 'your_github_email'
const githubPassword = 'your_github_password'

describe('Login with github credentials', () => {
    beforeEach(()=>{
        cy.visit('https://github.com/login');
        cy.get('#login_field').type(githubEmail);
        cy.get('#password').type(githubPassword);
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
    })
    it('Get SMS and apply it in 2FA form', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${accountSid}/Messages.json`,
            auth: {
                username: accountSid,
                password: authToken,
                AuthMethod: 'BasicAuth',
            }
        })
            .its('body').then((res) => {
            cy.wait(1500) //wait for SMS
            const otpcode = res.messages[0].body.substring(0, 6)
            cy.get('#otp').type(otpcode);
            cy.url().should('eq', 'https://github.com/');
        })
    });
});
```